# "Go To Definition" not working in VS2022 when editing JavaScript

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have just begun using VS2022 to edit JavaScript files. Prior to this, I was using VS2019.

A key editing feature that works in VS2019 does *not* work in VS2022: [F12] "Go To Definition". In VS2019, if you highlight something (a variable name, a function name, etc.) and press [F12], the editor goes to wherever that symbol is defined. In VS2022, nothing happens.

I have checked that the Keyboard assignment is correct, i.e., in VS2022 Options/Environment/Keyboard, [F12] is assigned to Edit.GoToDefinition. That matches VS2019.

My function keys are not remapped to other values.

After some web searches, it seems that if there is some loosely-described issue with the language engine, [F12] may not work. Those comments indicated that other features that depend on the language engine would also not work, for example, renaming a variable. I checked, and renaming via [F2] works as expected.

A similar feature, using [ALT+\] "Go To Members", also works. It's not as convenient because of (A) the awkward key combination and (B) it opens a small dialog popup where you have to select the matching item, even if there is only one. I mention "Go To Members" because it seems to depend on the same basic features of the language engine, i.e., the knowledge of where things are defined.

Have anyone else had trouble with [F12] / "Go To Definition", and if so, how did you fix it?

Comment: Well I'm seeing the same issue with VS 2022 and the ide stops responding every time I do F12. But I have been using VS 2022 for about 2 months now and so far it was working and suddenly this problem appears. I have restarted the VS several times but no use. By any chance @Johnny Cee Did you find a fix?

Comment: @jamilia, F12 works for me now. A few weeks back, while installing the update to v17.4.0, I added the "ASP.NET and web development" which was unchecked/not installed. After that update, F12 started working. I do not know which action fixed it, (A) the update or (B) the addition of the "ASP.NET and web development" component.

Comment: I have the same issue and googled but there is not resource to help. @Johnny did you find solution?

Comment: @Thomas.Benz, please see my comment above.